# VBA Set range from cell to last column with value

Tags: excel, vba

I have set range from cell "U7" to "HV7".
Purpose of this range is to count values in it.

Current code is working, but I would like to escape possibility of values beyond HV column, by selecting to last value.

```
Dim countRange As Range
Set countRange = Range("U7:HV7")

Dim rowcount As Long
rowcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(countRange)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba

Comment: Do you want to **include** values beyond HV in the count if they exist? If so, try `Set countRange = Range("U7", Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))`

Comment: @SuperSymmetry this is exactly what I wanted to do, just did not know how to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SuperSymmetry provided me with desired solution.

```
Set countRange = Range("U7", Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
```

Values in my table are proper formatted so I could with this solution select all from cell U7 to the last value on the right.